# Why is this legal in C?

Tags: c, language-design

I am writing a toy C compiler for a compiler/language course at my university.

I'm trying to flesh out the semantics for symbol resolution in C, and came up with this test case which I tried against regular compilers clang & gcc.

```
void foo() { }
int main() { foo(5); } // foo has extraneous arguments
```

Most compilers only seem to warn about extraneous arguments.

**Question: What is the fundamental reasoning behind this?**

For my symbol table generation/resolution phase, I was considering a function to be a symbol with a return type, and several parametrized arguments (based on the grammar) each with a respective type.

Thanks.

Comment: this is program is not strictly conforming, see my answer

Answer (score 32):

A function with *no* listed arguments in the prototype is deemed to have an *indeterminate* number, not zero.

If you really want zero arguments, it should be:

```
void foo (void);
```

The empty-list variant is a holdover from ancient C, even before ANSI got their hands on it, where you had things like:

```
add_one(val)
int val;
{
    return val + 1;
}
```

(with `int` being the default return type and parameter types specified outside the declarator).

If you're doing a toy compiler and you're not worried about compliance with *every* tiny little piece of C99, I'd just toss that option out and require a parameter list of some sort.

It'll make your life substantially easier, and I question the need for people to use that "feature" anyway.

Comment: Great side note. I didn't know this about C.

Comment: Not that it matters much, but your function header is wrong. It should be: `add_one(val) int val; [...]` Parameters can also take advantage of the default int rule, though, so you can eliminate the `int val;` (but if it wasn't an int you'd still need, for example, `long val;`).

Comment: Thanks, @Jerry, it's been a while since I wrote code like that :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: Sure. I remember, because every once in a while I decide to express my insanity in the form of code golf, and a parameter lets you define a local `int` using 5 fewer characters than a normal definition. :-)

Comment: Now I wonder if ancient features that nobody ever really uses unless they maintain 3000-year old code chiseled on stone tablets should be removed from either the language standard or the compilers, to make them easier to maintain.

Comment: @Cthulhu: Yes, people wonder that all the time. Then they go and actually drop features, and promptly someone pops up whose super-important, business-critical app depends on that exact ancient feature...

Comment: But, @pax, what about code golf? K&R style declarations are essential!

Answer (score 17):

It's for backward compatibility with *ancient* C compilers. Back before the earth cooled, all C function declarations looked roughly like:

```
int foo();
long bar();
```

and so on. This told the compiler that the name referred to a function, but did *not* specify anything about the number or types of parameters. Probably the single biggest change in the original (1989) C standard was adding "function prototypes", which allowed the number and type(s) of parameters to be declared, so the compiler could check what you passed when you called a function. To maintain compatibility for existing code, they decided that an empty parameter list would retain its existing meaning, and if you wanted to declare a function that took no parameters, you'd have to add `void` in place of the parameter list: `int f(void);`.

Note that in C++ the same is *not* true -- C++ eliminates the old style function declarations, and requires that the number and type(s) of all parameters be specified<sup>1</sup>. If you declare the function without parameters, that means it doesn't take any parameters, and the compiler will complain if you try to pass any (unless you've also overloaded the function so there's another function with the same name that *can* take parameters).

<sup>1</sup> Though you can still use an ellipsis for a function that takes a variable parameter list -- but when/if you do so, you can only pass POD types as parameters.

Comment: Congrats, Jerry, you are the proud winner of my 2000th upvote :-)

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the variable parameter list

Answer (score 5):

You haven't provided a prototype for the `foo` function, so the compiler can't enforce it.

If you wrote:

```
void foo(void) {}
```

then you would be providing a prototype of a function that takes no parameters.

gcc's `-Wstrict-prototypes` will catch this.  For an error, use `-Werror=strict-prototypes`.  The standard never specifies whether something should be a warning or an error.

Answer (score 4):

> Why is this legal in C?

First just to clarify the C Standard does not use the word *legal*.

In the C terminology, this program is **not strictly conforming**:

```
void foo() { }
int main() { foo(5); } // foo has extraneous arguments
```

When compiling this program, no diagnostic is required because of the function call `foo(5)`: there is no constraint violation.  But calling the function `foo` with an argument invokes undefined behavior. As any program that invokes undefined behavior, it is not strictly conforming and a compiler has the right to refuse to translate the program.

In the C Standard, a function declaration with an empty list of parameters means the function has an unspecified number of parameters. But a function definition with an empty list of parameters means the function has no parameter.

Here is the relevant paragraph in the C Standard (all emphasis mine):

> (C99, 6.7.5.3p14) "An identifier list declares only the identifiers of the parameters of the function. An empty list in a function declarator that is part of a definition of that function **specifies that the function has no parameters.**"

The paragraph of the C Standard that says the `foo(5)` call is undefined behavior is this one:

> (C99, 6.5.2.2p6) "**If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a prototype**, the integer promotions are performed on each argument, and arguments that have type float are promoted to double. These are called the default argument
>   promotions. **If the number of arguments does not equal the number of parameters, the
>   behavior is undefined**."

And from (C99, 6.9.1p7), we know the definition of `foo` does not provide a prototype.

> (C99, 6.9.1p7) "If the declarator includes a parameter type list, the  list also specifies the types of all the parameters; such a declarator also serves as a function prototype for later calls to the same function in the same translation unit. If the declarator includes an identifier list,the types of the parameters shall be declared in a following declaration list."

See the Committee answer to the Defect Report #317 for an authoritative answer on the subject:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_317.htm

Comment: A program which can execute a function call with incorrect arguments is not strictly conforming, but a strictly-conforming program may contain such function calls if they are never executed; consequently, the mere existence of such function calls may not prevent a conforming compiler from correctly processing a program containing them.